# Extract audio amplitude from video

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, video-processing

I need to process >200 videos by getting several snapshots from each one.
Each snapshot will be taken if the volume is higher than 'x'.
So I can make snapshots with FFMPEG but I don't know how to extract the amplitude graph.
How can I get an array with the audio volume of each frame?

Answer (score 0):

each frame have two timestamp , one is dts（decoder decode it from dts,so it means decode time stamp）,another is pts(playback timestamp)
so when av_decode_audio run,  get raw audio data ,you can check if its volume higher than 'x',if yes,get pts from audio frame.then you check video frames to get the correct one